# Windows 10 Audio Issues

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, lenovo-laptop, realtek-hd-audio

After the last 2 windows updates i am having issue with my audio jack on my laptop. Currently my audio jack is not detecting any devices. When i plug in my headphones nothing happens as in it does not show up in playback devices. Please see below the options i tried to resolve the issue but still no luck.

1. Updated Realtek audio driver.
2. Uninstalled/Reinstalled Realtek audio driver.
3. Looked at playback devices and ensured that "Showed disabled devices" and "Show disconnected devices" are ticked. My device is still not listed.
4. Tried rolling back windows update.(Windows giving me an error, not sure why)
5. Manually uninstalling each update.
6. Tried system restore.(Never activated the feature)
7. Tried the window troubleshooter.

I am honestly avoiding reinstalling windows as i have so many applications installed. I also checked if the sound card is fine and according to windows it is OK. I will really appreciate the advice you guys can give me, also please see below my device specs:

Model: Lenovo v110-15isk

Windows Version: Windows 10 PRO 1803

Comment: You *might* image the system and update to v. 1809, to see if that helps... knowing that there are new issues with that update disabling the Admin account (https://betanews.com/2019/01/02/windows-10-1809-administrator-account/) . With a disk image, though you could get back to v. 1803 with only broken sound devices.

Comment: Try Windows *Troubleshooting > Hardware and Sound > Troubleshoot audio playback*.

Comment: Hey DrMoishe, thanks so much for your response. I am on the latest update for Windows 10 on my device.

Comment: Hey Harry, thanks for your response. I actually did that but forgot to add to my list.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the latest BIOS update and the latest chipset drivers and the latest audio driver. It may be that the Win 10 installer has installed a generic driver. Get the drivers from Lenovo.
Google "lenovo v110-15isk drivers" without the quotes.

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/au/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v110-15isk/downloads

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/au/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v110-15isk/downloads/ds119358

In the Start menu, Windows Administrative Tools ==> System Information will tell you your existing BIOS version.
Device Manager can tell you the maker of the driver and the version for each device. Hint: right click the device and select Properties and look around.